# Show that $G=S_3S_5\rtimes S_2$ where $|G|=30$ and $S_p$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group of order $30$ and let $S_p<G$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup for $p=2,3,5$. Show that $G=S_3S_5\rtimes S_2$ (interior semi direct product).

I managed to show that $S_3S_5\cap S_2=\{e\}$ and that $S_3S_5\triangleleft G$ but **I'm not being able to show that $G=S_3S_5S_2$**.

Things I've proven that might be useful:

1. $|S_3S_5|=15$ thus $S_3S_5$ is a cyclic group.
2. $S_3\triangleleft G\lor S_5\triangleleft G$.
3. $S_2, S_3$ and $S_5$ are all cyclic (of course)

I tried assuming $g=a^mb^nc^r$ where $g$ is an arbitrary element of $G$ and $\langle a\rangle =S_2$, $\langle b\rangle=S_3$, $\langle c\rangle=S_5$ and $m,n,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ but didn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: @crystal_math , not really. Is the statement not true?

Comment: If you really know that $S_3S_5\triangleleft G$, then note $|(S_3S_5)S_2| = |S_3S_5|\,|S_2|/|(S_3S_5)\cap S_2|$. That shows that $G=S_3S_5S_2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin And if you know that $\vert S_3S_5 \vert=15$, then you know $[G:S_3S_5]=2$, so $S_3S_5 \triangleleft G$.

Comment: @RobertShore Well, all groups of order 15 are also cyclic and thus a normal subgroup.

Comment: @RandomUser That's not true.  It doesn't even make sense.  You can only talk about whether a subgroup is normal in the context of a larger group.  So a group of order $15$ may be a normal subgroup of one group but not a normal subgroup of a different group.  In fact, let $H$ be the unique (up to isomorphism) group of order $15$ and embed $H$ in a group $G$ such that $H$ is not normal in $G$.  Now consider $K=H \times G$.  One copy of $H$ is normal in $K$, but another is not.

Comment: @RobertShore My bad you are right. I got it mixed up with the property "every subgroup of a cyclic group is normal". What is not true is that every cyclic sub group of a group is normal.